# Issues with triggering mulitple css animations on scroll

Tags: javascript, css-animations, onscrolllistener

I'm not good with JS and struggle with triggering multiple CSS animations when they come into view.
So for I only manage to trigger one animation despite having three intersections that supposedly target the different elements. All I want to fill the bars to different widths which I have specified with keyframes. The section of the code is in the codepen. Could some help me out with it?
https://codepen.io/asmmargod/pen/QWzOeQx

I tried adding new observers to target different elements but they come out with the same width.

I made separate observers for each element but the resulting efect shows the same animations on three elements

```
     const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
           entry.target.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector(".various__item--skills-fill-1"));

const observer1 = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add("active-2");
    }
  });
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector(".various__item--skills-fill-2"));
const observer2 = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add("active-3");
    }
  });
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector(".various__item--skills-fill-3"));`
```

Comment: To start with **avoid**  showcasing your skills, knowledge, tech-stack proficiency etc. in percentages, gauges, sliders, or whatever. What means 70%? What means 100%?...  you got the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ForEach your elements
- Use CSS `var()` to customize the percentage

```js
const inViewport = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    entry.target.classList.toggle("active", entry.isIntersecting);
  });
};

const Obs = new IntersectionObserver(inViewport);
document.querySelectorAll(".skill").forEach(el => Obs.observe(el));
```

```css
.skill {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  transition: all 4s;
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg, #f00 0%, #f00 100%) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(0deg, #0000 30%, #aaa 30%, #aaa 70%, #0000 70%) no-repeat
  ;
  background-size: 0%, 100%;
}

.skill.active {
  background-size: calc(var(--percent) * 1%), 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill" style="--percent:95;">HTML</div>
<div class="skill" style="--percent:60;">CSS</div>
<div class="skill" style="--percent:78;">JS</div>
```

Comment: Thank you with your help it was helpful. The progress bar is an idea from a portofolio webpage I'm recreating so I can learn. I agree is not the best idea to quantify skill this way.

Comment: @asmmargod you're welcome. Glad it helped!